# SQL query datetime select 24 hour before

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Good evening. I'm writing a sql query to select records 24 hour before start_time (to send email reminder).
start_time - is a time when class should be started.

For example: start_time is tomorrow: at 16:30 (2020-11-26 16:55:00)

I took 30 minutes time bufer (just n case of any latency).

so my query would be like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM classes 
WHERE start_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR AND
start_time <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1410 MINUTE
```

(24 hours = 1440 minutes, so subtract 30 = 1410 minutes).
But query returns 0, can't understand why.

Please point me where I'm wrong, thanks.

Comment: Presumably there were no records during that time.

Comment: when I execute SELECT * 
FROM classes 
WHERE start_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR - I got the record, but when add another part of the query - 0 results

Comment: NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR looks like 24 hours in the past to me (forgive me, this looks like MySql-specific syntax). If this is so, then the query is looking for start_time's in the 30 minutes starting 24 hours ago which is not what you said you were after.

Comment: You can easily test what now() is and what now() adjusted is by simply selecting.